# Kotlin coroutine in Spring DataJpaTest

Tags: kotlin, spring-data-jpa, kotlin-coroutines

In a spring Boot service we have a new Kotlin coroutine implementation which works nicely.

However, when trying to test it the JpaRepository seems to get "truncated" when accessed on a coroutine block. here is a simplified portion of the code:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension
import javax.persistence.*

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = [SpringTestConfig::class])
@DataJpaTest
class BadRepoTest(@Autowired val testedRepository: TestRepository) {
    @Test
    fun testRepo() {

        testedRepository.saveAndFlush(TestEntity())

        println("count at start: ${testedRepository.count()} and $testedRepository")
        runBlocking {
            runCodeAsync().await()
        }
        println("count post async code: ${testedRepository.count()} and $testedRepository")
    }

    fun runCodeAsync(): Deferred<Unit> {
        return GlobalScope.async {
            println("count in async code: ${testedRepository.count()} and $testedRepository")
        }
    }
}

interface TestRepository : JpaRepository<TestEntity, Int>

@Entity
@Table(name = "test")
data class TestEntity(
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) val id: Int? = null
)
```

I would expect the repository to contain a single entity at all time during the test run, but the code prints:

```
count at the start: 1 and SimpleJpaRepository@40d04cf8
count in async code: 0 and SimpleJpaRepository@40d04cf8
count post async code: 1 and SimpleJpaRepository@40d04cf8
```

Could you please advise?

Comment: You may be violating the threading policy of the implicit ORM session in use. You use `save` from one thread, switch to another thread to query, then do the last check from the original thread. The `save` command probably doesn't commit the transaction and the other thread starts its own, concurrent transaction isolated from the original one.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik 10x. to rule that out, I've changed the save(...) to saveAndFlush(...) - to no avail.

Comment: I wouldn't even expect that to make a difference. `save()` does nothing but enroll your object into the local cache, whereas `saveAndFlush()` immediately executes an `INSERT` statement. Both are transaction-local actions and aren't visible outside it.